# Wrong encoding in ZipFile comment

Tags: c#, zip

I'm reading the comment of a ZIP file using the Ionic.Zip.ZipFile class and there seem to be a problem with accented characters (like éêè). 
In my case, instead of receiving "Éric", I get "╔ric".

My code is :

```
using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(path))
{
  comment = zipFile.Comment;
}
```

Path is the path of the ZIP File.
I also tried to put the encoding directly, but same result (like this) :

```
using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(path, Encoding.UTF8))
{
  comment = zipFile.Comment;
}
```

Is there a specific encoding for the comment?

Comment: What Zip library are you using?  System.IO.Compression.ZipFile has no such constructor.  The comment aspect of the ZIP file format is a mess.  It looks like Unicode was hacked into the Zip format.  If I read the spec correctly, there are two comment fields: an old one, and a new Unicode one.  There is a field to determine the format of the comment.  I'm not sure any of this helps since it is probably determined by the library you are using. See http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT

Comment: I'm using the Ionic.Zip.dll like I said at the beginning of my post.

Comment: Sorry for missing the library.  I use that library too but I have never had to deal with Unicode file names or comments.  There is a bug report for this back in 2011, but they claim to have fixed it. https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/10392 and an even older one too https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/workitem/3152  Are you sure the Zip file was written correctly?  Do other apps show the comment correctly?

Comment: WinZip or WinRar where showing the comment correctly.
I found the solution within your first link and post it as the answer. I will accept it as the answer when I will be able to (in 2 days).
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Moby Disk, I found the solution.
You need to get the right encoding of the comment before encoding it to the one you use (in my case the default one).

The code is as follow :

```
using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(path))
{
  byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(437).GetBytes(zipFile.Comment);
  comment = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
}
```

Comment: I am glad I could point you in the right direction.  There is nothing wrong with answering your own question though, so feel free to accept it.  With this solution, are you limited to characters that are in the 437 code page?

Comment: I will probably be limited with this range of characters, but in my case, this is fine. There won't be any other character in the comment of the zip file than the list I saw, because there will only be client names, version numbers and dates in it.